# How to check if the user has mentioned everyone or here?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make a command where the bot replies the ping of the bot with "Hello this is my prefix". But the bot also replies to @everyone and @here. How do I prevent that?

this is my code till now

```
if(message.mentions.has(client.user)){
    
    message.reply('My prefix is `.`');
  }
```

Comment: Ohh i think I didn found a way i tried
`if(message.mentions.has(client.user)&& !message.mentions.everyone){
    
    message.reply('My prefix is `.`');
  }
`
ad it worked

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have already found a solution by now, but if someone were to come across this looking for something similar here you go:

```
if(message.mentions.everyone === true){
    message.reply('My prefix is `.`');
  }
```

Personally, if I were you, instead of adding this in with another if statement I would just keep it in the same if statement like this:

```
if(message.mentions.has(client.user) || message.mentions.everyone === true){
    message.reply('My prefix is `.`');
  }
```

Assuming you're new to JS, the `||` basically means "or", so I'm saying "if the mention, mentions the bot OR mentions everyone (@everyone/@here), I want to send my prefix". The `||` (or) is one of many logical operators in JavaScript, and are very useful, if you find the operators confusing, try reading this: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp